# How to carry a check box variable to another page - PHP

Tags: php, html

I have 5 checkboxes on page 1 and want to fetch rows onto page 2 from database basis on this.

Example:

```
if checkbox1 = checked    
    fetch row 1

if checkbox2 = checked    
    fetch row 2

...
```

and so on.

Just provide me with an **idea** of how to write the syntax for this in PHP.

Comment: ideas are precious , please share your code

Comment: Give your checkbox input a value property and post it to the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this idea

```
<form action="table2.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name='ch1' value="1"> 
<input type="checkbox" name='ch2'  value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name='ch3' value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name='ch4' value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name='ch5'  value="5">
</form>
```

And **table2.php**

```
<?php
    for($i=1;$i<6;$i++)
    {

            $fetch=$_POST['ch'.$i];
            if($fetch==$i)
            {
                //fetch row $i
            }

    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can post all your checkboxes using the post method and then check each one of them in your action page.

If you give them the same name, they would be an array, so you can traverse them using their indexes.

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

in page2.php

```
$checkArray = $_POST['check'];
$i = 0;
foreach ($checkArray as $checkVal) {
    //some dao you can use with $i
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: And how would I call that checkbox value on other page?

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['checkX'])) {...}`

Comment: @LostMohican - What is $checkVal ?

Comment: @Niks $checkVal is the value that you get from the checkbox array.